# WP7 Tombstoning and Querystring

Tags: windows-phone-7, query-string, tombstoning

I am running very basic xml reader and I pass some data to the details page by using:

```
    private void HaberlerListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/News.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            FrameworkElement root = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root.DataContext = (HaberItem)e.AddedItems[0];

            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```

For a week I am trying to read and understand how to deal with Tombstoning but I failed. I managed to use Tombstone Helper but i couldn't save images and webbrowser content.

In the earlier question: [WP7 - Resume from the page I assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731228/wp7-resume-from-the-page-i-assigned) . I heard that I can save the navigation url so when the user clicks back wp7 will navigate to the same url like before. (For the records:I don't use ViewModel)

I would like to get your view on how to save this url so My damned :) application can tombstone and I can rest a while :D.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page URI, including querystring, is restored when an application returns from its tombstoned state. Rather that using Tombstone Helper I would recommend that you learn how tombstoning actually works, have a read of this article:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/

It's not too complicated.

Comment: Thanks Colin. Your tutorial has been so useful to me. It took some time but I did it at last :P